Ubuntu 24.04 randomly freeze in to white screen while mining in the background
I installed ubuntu 24.04 and use it as my daily driver but it been having this problem where randomly it goes to white screen (death, as I can't do anything other than hard reboot).
The gpu and cpu is still working but it doesn't seem to do anything as the system crash.
Mining on both the cpu and GPU so it is at 100% at all time.
Notice that this hqppen randomly but mostly happen when I using edge web brower to play music or stuff.
Is there anyway to fix it?
Hardware, Ryzen 9 9900x, 32GB using. Around 12GB, 7900xtx 24G
